# Generate feature.cs file in a different location than the feature file - SpecFlow.xUnit 3.6.23

Tags: xunit, specflow, .net-5

I'm trying to achieve the following:-
My feature files are in a separate repo. I include the external repo into my `dotnet` repo using `git subrepo`. When i build my `dotnet` sln, the `feature.cs` file gets generated at the same location as the `.feature` file. Basically in the tracked git subrepo folder. I would like my `feature.cs` file to be generated in a location different from the `.feature` file location. Can that be done? I'm on `.net5.0` and using SpecFlow 3.6.23 (via Specflow.xUnit 3.6.3) and xUnit Test Runner

Comment: Wouldn't be possible to add *.feature.cs into the .gitignore of the subrepo?

Answer (score 1):

Feature.cs files will always be generated in the project where the feature file is.

The only option you have is to copy the feature files into the location where you want to have the `feature.cs` files at the end.

We are doing this in SpecFlow itself, as we copy some feature files from cucumber for testing.

We are doing this with a custom MSBuild Target:

```
 <Target Name="IncludeCucumberMessagesSpecs" BeforeTargets="BeforeUpdateFeatureFilesInProject" Condition="$(DesignTimeBuild) != 'true' OR '$(BuildingProject)' == 'true'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CucumberMessagesSpecFlowFeatureFiles)" DestinationFolder="Features/CucumberMessages" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CucumberMessagesSpecFlowFeatureFiles Include="Features/CucumberMessages/*.feature" />

      <_CucumberMessagesSpecFlowFeatureFiles>
        <CodeBehindFile>Features/CucumberMessages/%(Filename).feature$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)</CodeBehindFile>
        <Visible>$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)</Visible>
      </_CucumberMessagesSpecFlowFeatureFiles>

      <SpecFlowFeatureFiles Include="@(_CucumberMessagesSpecFlowFeatureFiles)" Exclude="@(SpecFlowFeatureFiles)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

From https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/master/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs.csproj#L78